# Use verb in -masu form + kana to wonder about something instead of using the -darou form

Tags: grammar, verbs

The following sentence (in a context which is speaking about a woman):

> 青いワンピースを着て、どこに行くんだろう。

Can be translated as:

> Where is she going in a blue dress?

Could I use「かな？」instead of the「ーだろう」form? E.g.:

> 青いワンピースを着て、どこに行きますかな。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 青いワンピースを着て、どこに行きますかな。

doesn't sound natural (at least in modern standard Japanese), I'm afraid. The polite form of 「～だろう」 is 「～でしょう」. (行きます is the polite form of 行く, as you may know.)

> 青いワンピースを着て、どこに行くのでしょう。/ 行くんでしょう。
> "I wonder where (she) is going in a blue dress."

---

Using かな, you can say:

> 青いワンピースを着て、どこに行く**のかな**。

This would mean almost the same thing as your original sentence.